# Do not accept starting with zero in register

Tags: android

I programming  a new user registration interface and in the Verify fields, register the phone number
When starting to register the number at zero does not accept starting with zero, what is the solution?
example: 0575 don't accept but if start 50 accept that.

Comment: You should try regular expression with edittext watcher or listener

Comment: Is this a numeric field; try using a string

Answer (score 1):

```
if (stringVariable.startsWith("0")) {
    // Do not accept the registration
}
```